# Append a class object to an array

Tags: swift

I am having trouble with the syntax here. Basically I created a simple class and hoping to add the object of that class to an Array.

```
class simpleClass {
    var aNum = Int()
    var aWord = String()
    init(thisNum:Int,thisString:String)
    {
        aNum = thisNum
        aWord = thisString
    }
}

var aObj:simpleClass
var aArray:Array<simpleClass>
aObj = simpleClass(thisNum:12,thisString:"Test")
aArray.append(aObj)
```

As you can see I have created an object of simpleClass and trying to append it to an array of type simpleClass. However, I receive an error saying

**passed by reference before being initialized**

I guess I must be missing something in the syntax. Hoping someone out there could point out my mistake.

thanks,
sweekim

Comment: You forgot to initialise the array.  var aArray:Array<SimpleClass> = Array()

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an array to the array variable.

```
var aArray:Array<simpleClass> = []
```

Or if you prefer,

```
var aArray = Array<simpleClass>()
```

Or even (my preference)

```
var aArray: [simpleClass] = []
```

Or

```
var aArray = [simpleClass]()
```

Better yet you could even reorder things and do this:

```
var aArray = [simpleClass(thisNum:12,thisString:"Test")]
```

instead of the whole 4 last lines.

Incidentally, you might find it better to declare your class like this:

```
class simpleClass {
    var aNum: Int
    var aWord: String
    init(thisNum:Int,thisString:String) {
        aNum = thisNum
        aWord = thisString
    }
}
```

This types `aNum` and `aWord`, but does not assign them values, since you then do that in the `init` method.  The reason being, if you ever forgot to assign a value in `init` the compiler will warn you, whereas if you default them, it won’t.  It’s fine to default them instead, but then don’t include them in an `init` method – one or the other is best, both is a bit redundant and can lead to mistakes.

Comment: You still didn't show him the one I would have used. :)

Comment: I probably edited it in now. Personally I don't care for that one, don't know why it's so popular :)

Comment: You’re welcome – though if it answered the question, the way to say thanks is to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
var aArray:Array<simpleClass>
```

To this:

```
var aArray:Array<simpleClass> = []
```

You were declaring the array type but you forgot to make any array. If you actually *look* at the error message, it tells you exactly that - you didn't initialize the variable.

Comment: I dunno, that message is a bit misleading, especially "by reference" for a value type. Normally it would be something more obvious like "aArray used before being initialized"

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity The "by reference" is because `append` is `mutating`; it _is_ by reference in the same way that `inout` is by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Also I think you didn't quite declare your instance of simpleClass correctly.  I did this to silence the errors:

```
var aArray:Array<simpleClass> = []
let aObj:simpleClass = simpleClass(thisNum:12,thisString:"Test")
aArray.append(aObj)
```

Note the way an instance of simpleClass is created.